# Wireless Router Connection Notifications

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router, notifications

For Windows 7, is there, ideally, a small program for the task bar that shows a list of all devices/MAC Addresses that are connected to the wireless router, and perhaps also notifies when a new computer is connected or disconnected?

I already know that it's possible to check connected devices in my wireless router settings.

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but I use Fing on my iPod Touch. I just leave it beside my PC. https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8

Comment: Thanks, I installed Fing on my Galaxy Nexus.  It's a really nice tool.

Comment: Great to hear. I've been searching for a similar tool for Windows to no avail, that is my solution for now. I assumed that a network admin would have created a tool, but perhaps not.

Comment: it is also available for Windows, Mac OS and Linux, but as Command Line tools.  i definitely agree it would be nice if the desktop versions had a GUI like the mobile versions.  http://www.overlooksoft.com/download